# Doesn't work macros for environment variables in Windows 7

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have set `JAVA_HOME` variable
And also I have set path variable:

```
C:\>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38

C:\>set path
Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\To
rtoiseSVN\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\apach\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\>java -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

At this way java is not recognized.

Lets change a bit(replace `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin`):

```
C:\>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38

C:\>set path
Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\To
rtoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin;C:\Program Files\apach\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

For this way it is working good.

What do I wrong?

Comment: From the top of my head.. Did you restart the cmd prompt after setting path?

Comment: Yes, surely I restarted cmd after each environment variable change

Comment: downvoter, please explain your vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"` is a perfectly valid directory name. `cmd` would need to evaluate its value before it could be used.

```
call set path=%path%
```

should work for you.

---

Expansion

`path` is loaded with the `system` value, then merged with the 'user' value, when any %var% in the path is replaced by its then-current value. If you add another `%var%` into the path (like for instance, as a "user" variable) then you need to re-evaluate to resolve the value.

The upshot is: set the path as a system variable, not a user variable if it contains a value to be resolved.

Comment: Can you explain more details? I am sure that before it worked without this unclear directive.